# Power BI Connector for to prepare Power BI user activities dashboard

Tags: powerbi

We want to create Power BI dashboard highlighting statistics of user activities related to Power BI for last 30/90 days.

Below are the high level statistics we want to capture:

1. Created Power BI dashboard
2. Created Power BI report
3. Edited Power BI dashboard
4. Edited Power BI report
5. Printed Power BI dashboard
6. Shared Power BI dashboard
7. Viewed Power BI dashboard
8. Viewed Power BI report
9. Statistics of Power BI active users

Would want to know if there is any available solution or OOB Power BI connector for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Use the tenancy audit logs or O365 logs which will give you some insight. You have to extract them then surface them in a report

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze statistics of user activities using the Power BI Activity log. You can download the activities by using a REST API or PowerShell cmdlet. You can also filter the activity data by date range, user, and activity type. In order to be able to do this, you should be a Power BI Service Admin. You have to install the Power BI Management cmdlets locally or use the Power BI Management cmdlets in Azure Cloud Shell.

You will find more details here : https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-power-bi-activity-log-makes-it-easy-to-download-activity-data-for-custom-usage-reporting/

Answer (score 0):

To check 30 days statistics Power BI has "Usage metrics" features for every report. Other than this you can use your O365 data if you are an admin of Power BI services

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

The easy one:

go to a report, get the "usage metrics" then delete the filter applied to this report. You now have a "global usage metrics" for every report in the tenant.
pro: easy, cons: you don't have everything.

The hard one:

@Trisa Biswas answer is correct, you can use the rest api to get everything you need.
Pro: it's complete. cons: it's more complicated.

PS: to get the usage metrics:

Open a report online,  "...", get usage metrics, save a copy in your workspace, delete the filter "ReportGuid".